# Apache2 require login but allow access to php?

Tags: apache, apache2

Is it possible to restrict access to people who wants to get on the server by making them enter a password but allow php to use file_get_contents? That's currently not working as php is getting a 401 error.

I tried `Allow from 127.0.0.1` and `Satisfy any` but it doesn't seems to work as it will grant permission to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't solve the root of the problem but you can use [`stream_context_create`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#74431) to add authentication data - the link points at a comment that shows an example. After creating the context you can continue to use `file_get_contents`.